# PHPExcel memory still exhausted even with cell caching - other solutions

Tags: php, caching, memory, phpexcel

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes) in <b>/var/www/leanne/api/classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/PHPTemp.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />
```

Hi,

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586694/phpexcel-how-to-write-to-file-in-chunks) a few days ago and was advised to change my code and to use cell caching. While I have changed my code and attempted to use cell caching, I am still getting a memory error. I am desperate to find a solution to this.

Can anyone advise on which caching method would be best for writing excel files ranging between 1 to 100,000 rows of data?  If cell caching doesn't work, I may need to use another solution that allows me to append to an xls file in the same way I do with the CSV version.

An example of my current code is below:

```
if ($count_prods > 0) {

    $format = strtolower($export_data['output']);
    $temp_file_location = '../temp/exports/products/';
    $filename = 'data_' + $shop->ID . '_' . $export_id . '_test';
    $separator = ',';
    $endrow = "\n";

    $fh = fopen($temp_file_location . $filename . '.csv', 'a');

    /*$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array( ' memoryCacheSize ' => '8MB');
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);*/

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_sqlite;
    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $rowID = 2;
    $counter = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_prods; $i += $batchlimit) {
        $csv = '';
        $limit = $batchlimit * $counter;
        $start = $i + 1;
        $productData = $productExport->getProductData($start, $limit);

        if ($counter == 1) {
            //get column names
            if ($format == 'csv') {
                $column_titles = implode(',', $productExport->product_fields);
                $column_no = count($column_titles);
                $csv = $column_titles . $endrow;
            } else {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($productExport->product_fields, NULL, 'A1');
            }
        }

        //loop through data export array
        foreach ($productData as $product_id => $product_details) {
            $columnID = 'A';
            foreach ($product_details as $key => $value) {
                if ($format == 'csv') {
                    $csv .= '"' . str_replace('"', '\'', $product_details[$key]) . '"' . $separator;
                } else {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID . $rowID, $product_details[$key]);
                }
                $columnID++;
            }
            if ($format == 'csv') {
                $csv = rtrim($csv, $separator);
                $csv .= $endrow;
            }
            $rowID++;
        }
        if ($format == 'csv') {
            fwrite($fh, $csv);
            $csv = '';
        }

        $counter++;
    }
    if ($format == 'csv') {
        fclose($fh);
    }

    //if  XLS file 
    if ($format == 'xls') {
        //$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($temp_file_location . $filename . '.csv');
        // $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        //$objWriter->save($temp_file_location . $filename . '.xls');
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
        $objWriter->save($temp_file_location . $filename . '.xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: If cache_to_phpTemp doesn't work, which of the other caching strategies have you used? cache_to_sqlite or cache_to_sqlite3 are highly memory efficient

Comment: But if you have potentially 100,000 rows, don't use Excel5 (unless you split it across two worksheets) because Excel5 (BIFF format) is limited to 65535 rows per worksheet)

Comment: XLS only allows maximum 65,535 rows. Are you certain that's how many rows you need? How many sheets does your Excel workbook require?

Comment: I had tried a couple of other methods, none of which worked.  I haven't tried cache_to_sqlite as I can't find examples on how to implement this.  What should I use instead of Excel5?

Comment: yes, I'm 100% sure that is what I need, 105,688 is the largest file to be exact.  A single worksheet would be great. I know there must be a way to create large files as it is currently works but written in ASP, I am trying to rewrite in PHP.

Comment: and the CSV version works fine for 105,688 rows and opens in excel

Comment: Use Excel2007 if you want more than 65535 rows, because this format supports up to 1 million rows

Comment: Caching to sqlite is in the developer docs, section 4.2.1, also now on the PHPExcel wiki at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md

Comment: If the CSV solution works, why do you need an Excel solution then?

Comment: @silkfire - not certain of that myself either, if there was some Excel formatting in there (bold headings, use of formulae for totalling, autofilters, whatever)... but it's simply the same data as the csv without anything more that requires Excel

Comment: @LeeTee Really, your users are picky :) I mean if there's no formatting on the data then I see absolutely no reason to use Excel here.

Comment: there is formatting on the data, I just showed a simplified version of the code. There's always character encoding issues when opening a CSV in Excel so need to provide xls as an option.

Comment: I can give you a solution if it's okay to split the data onto 2 sheets equally.

Comment: @silkfire, that would be great, as I am having no luck at all with the cache_to_sqlite

Comment: Does your server allow maximum 128MB of memory? i'm referring to the PHP setting.

Comment: yeah its 128MB, I can increase it.  I have used ini_set to increase it as suggested below

Comment: Do you have sqlite or sqlite3 enabled in your PHP? If so, simply telling PHPExcel to use the appropriate one should work without issue - but test the return from `PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod(PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite);` IF IT DOESN'T WORK, let the devolopers know what isn't working

Comment: checked PHPinfo and sqlite3 is enabled.  Im wondering if the exhausted memory is because of something else in my code.  Perhaps the database, even though I am only getting data in batches of 1000...hmmm

Comment: If you do have a large array of product batches already fetched into memory, that certainly won't help

Answer (score 2):

PHPExcel is an excelent library, and I just love it. However, to support all those Excel features, it eats a lot of memory.

You are doing simple reading and writing, without any advanced Excel stuff.

Give Spout a try. https://github.com/box/spout

From the main description: 
*Spout is a PHP library to read and write spreadsheet files (CSV, XLSX and ODS), in a fast and scalable way. Contrary to other file readers or writers, it is capable of processing very large files while keeping the memory usage really low (less than 3MB).*

For exporting or importing from excel it is at least 10x faster and eats very little memory, as it is streaming data to and from the file

I have successfully replaced PHPExcel for some very big Excel files for which I only needed exporting data.

Answer (score 1):

you could increase the memory and time allocated to the script using:

ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
        set_time_limit('1200');

Comment: This does ensure the script continues running for longer but then I get error, "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to create or update an Excel file with potentially 100,000 rows of data and send it for download to the user. I have fiddled with large Excel files (1,500,000+ cells with lots of formulas) and in my experience you cannot achieve Excel file generation on the fly.